# How to put a function inside an object and directly output the result

Tags: javascript, oop

Look, I ve got the following code to be executed and the result expected:

```
a = { a: function(){ return 'red'} }
```

so whenever I call

```
a.a #=> I would like to receive 'red' rather than 'function(){ return 'red'}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: a.a => a.a() would invoke the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this

```
a = { 
   a: 'red' 
};
```

But if having the result return function that important, we have to make sure the function get called and returned.

```
a = {
    a: function() {
        return 'red-by-function';
    }() //This will ensure the function is called rather that returning the whole function
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wtkLm/1/) of both cases

Comment: Yup, second one is the one I was looking at!

Answer (score 1):

You need to finish this off as a closure:

```
a = { a: function(){ return 'red';}()};
```

Note the `();` at the end, which makes this a complete closure.